# Not receiving event notification from DocuSign API

Tags: docusignapi

I am using the DocuSign Rest API v2. During envelope creation process, we will send our rest API URL to receive the notifications.

The events are properly receiving in our live setup. But in our local development setup we are not receiving the notifications.

For this, we have whitelisted the IP ranges mentioned in the DocuSign Page on our side.
https://trust.docusign.com/en-us/trust-certifications/ip-ranges/

But still, we are not receiving notifications to the development setup.

What else we need to do to get this done?

Comment: Can you confirm that URL/endpoint for the demo/local environment are internet accessible? If you are trying to use an endpoint for DS Connect that only exists locally on a server it may not work if it is not accessible by the internet.

Comment: Additionally, I'd suggest that you check the Connect logs (as described here: https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-admin-guide-connect). Knowing the specific error that's being encountered will be helpful in troubleshooting.

Comment: @LuisScott The URL/endpoint for the demo/local environment is not internet accessible. But we have given access to all  DocuSign IP ranges. But we are not receiving the events.
 For my production account, the 'Connect' option is not shown in the admin Page. It is seen in my demo account.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I'm unable to respond to the original post, however I've experienced the same issue (reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38616583/docusign-api-envelope-sent-vie-rest-but-no-status-returned)).  It only appears to occur when envelopes are sent as far as I can tell, and I'm able to retrieve the status afterwards - but it's not in line with what the API guide tells us, nor what was happening previously.